# Calling Gradle buildConfig multiple times

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trouble figuring out a way to add multiple lines to my BuildConfig using Gradle. It appears that when I call buildConfig a 2nd time, the first one disappears.

I was originally adding this buildConfig from a different spot, but was able to create a minimal reproducible test if I do this:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
        buildConfig "public static final int THING_ONE = 1;"
        buildConfig "public static final int THING_TWO = 2;"
    }
    release {
        zipAlign true
        buildConfig "public static final int THING_ONE = 3;"
        buildConfig "public static final int THING_TWO = 4;"
    }
}
```

Then when I try to use it in code:

```
public class Thing {
    public static final int THING = com.example.BuildConfig.THING_ONE + com.example.BuildConfig.THING_TWO;
}
```

I will get this error:

```
/Example/src/main/java/com/example/Thing.java:2: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable THING_ONE
location: class com.example.BuildConfig
public static final int THING = com.example.BuildConfig.THING_ONE + com.example.BuildConfig.THING_TWO;
```

Is there any way to add multiple different lines to the buildConfig for each productFlavor or buildType (using multiple calls to buildConfig -- instead of a multi-line string)?

Comment: Try `buildConfigField` instead of `buildConfig`, if you are on 0.7.+ of the Gradle for Android plugin: `buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://stage.this-is-so-fake.com"'`

Comment: If you're looking for how to override buildConfigField values in BuildTypes, checkout @CommonsWare example : https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/0e5e5893df7a97823a100aa15d2d5bb961bfff71/Gradle/HelloBuildConfig/build.gradle

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @CommonsWare pointed out, since Gradle 1.9 (Android Studio 0.4.0) you have to declare your `BuildConfig` fields like that :

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
        buildConfigField "int", "THING_ONE", "1"
        buildConfigField "int", "THING_TWO", "2"
    }
}
```